# Logic: auxilliry lemma for tr_rev_correct

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

In Logic chapter a tail recursive version of reverse list function is introduced. We need to prove that it works correctly:

```
Fixpoint rev_append {X} (l1 l2 : list X) : list X :=
  match l1 with
  | [] => l2
  | x :: l1' => rev_append l1' (x :: l2)
  end.

(* Tail recursion rev *)
Definition tr_rev {X} (l : list X) : list X :=
  rev_append l [].
```

But before proving it I wanted to prove a lemma:

```
Lemma rev_append_app: forall (X: Type) (x: X) (l : list X),
    rev_append l [x] = rev_append l [] ++ [x].
Proof.
  intros X x l. induction l as [| h t IH].
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl.
```

Here I am stuck:

```
X : Type
x, h : X
t : list X
IH : rev_append t [x] = rev_append t [ ] ++ [x]
============================
rev_append t [h; x] = rev_append t [h] ++ [x]
```

What to do next?

Comment: A short answer is that this lemma is not easier to prove than the original one.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Please, give some hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you noticed during your attempted proof, when taking the induction step from `rev_append l [x]` to `rev_append (h :: t) [x]`, you end up with the term `rev_append t [h; x]` after simplification. The induction step does not lead towards the base case of the `rev_append` function, but to another recursive invocation that you cannot simplify.

Notice how the induction hypothesis that you would like to apply makes a statement about `rev_append t [x]` for some fixed `x`, but in your goal, the extra `h` list element before it gets in the way, and the induction hypothesis is of no use.

This is what Bubbler's answer was referring to when stating that your induction hypothesis is not strong enough: it only makes a statement about the case where the second argument is a list with a *single* element. But even after just the induction step (one recursive application), that list already has at least two elements!

As suggested by Bubbler, the helper lemma `rev_append l (l1 ++ l2) = rev_append l l1 ++ l2` is stronger and does not have this problem: when used as the induction hypothesis, it can be applied to `rev_append t [h; x]` as well, allowing you to prove equality with `rev_append t [h] ++ [x]`.

When attempting to prove the helper lemma, you may get stuck (like I did) in the same way as when proving `rev_append_app` itself. The crucial bit of advice that helped me proceed was to **be careful which of the universally quantified variables you introduce before you start the induction**. If you specialize any of them too early on, you might weaken your induction hypothesis and become stuck again. You may need to change the order of these quantified variables or use the `generalize dependent` tactic (see the [Tactics](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Tactics.html) chapter of *Logic Foundations*).

Answer (score 2):

You can see that the induction hypothesis `IH` is not strong enough to prove the goal. Here what you need is **a more general statement to prove in the first place**. You can find more exercises dedicated to this topic [here](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrw12/InductionExercises.html). (Actually, tail-recursive reverse is one of the exercises.)

In your case, the fully generalized statement could be as follows:

```
Lemma rev_append_app': forall (X: Type) (l l1 l2 : list X),
    rev_append l (l1 ++ l2) = rev_append l l1 ++ l2.
```

Proving this by induction is trivial. Then you can prove your own statement as a corollary of this one:

```
Corollary rev_append_app: forall (X: Type) (x: X) (l : list X),
    rev_append l [x] = rev_append l [] ++ [x].
Proof. intros. apply (rev_append_app _ _ [] [x]). Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

use the generalize dependent tactic like this:

```
Lemma rev_append_app: forall (X: Type) (l l1: list X) (x : X),
    rev_append l (l1 ++ [x]) = rev_append l l1 ++ [x].
  intros.
  generalize dependent l1.
  induction l as [| h t IH].
  - intros.
    easy.
  - intros.
    apply (IH (h::l1)).
Qed.
```