# SF Volume 1: Logic: How to prove tr_rev <-> rev?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, proof-of-correctness, proof-general

From Software Foundations Volume 1, chapter Logic we see a tail recursive definition of list reversal. It goes like so:

```
Fixpoint rev_append {X} (l1 l2 : list X) : list X :=
  match l1 with
  | [] => l2
  | x :: l1' => rev_append l1' (x :: l2)
  end.

Definition tr_rev {X} (l : list X) : list X :=
  rev_append l [].
```

We're, then, asked to prove the equivalence of `tr_rev` and `rev` which, well, is pretty obvious that they are the same. I'm having a hard time completing the induction, though. Would appreciate if the community would provide any hints as to how to approach this case.

Here's as far as I got:

```
Theorem tr_rev_correct : forall X, @tr_rev X = @rev X.
Proof.
  intros X. (* Introduce the type *)
  apply functional_extensionality. (* Apply extensionality axiom *)
  intros l. (* Introduce the list *)
  induction l as [| x l']. (* start induction on the list *)
  - reflexivity. (* base case for the empty list is trivial *)
  - unfold tr_rev. (* inductive case seems simple too. We unfold the definition *)
    simpl. (* simplify it *)
    unfold tr_rev in IHl'. (* unfold definition in the Hypothesis *)
    rewrite <- IHl'. (* rewrite based on the hypothesis *)
```

At this point, I have this set of hypothesis and goal:

```
  X : Type
  x : X
  l' : list X
  IHl' : rev_append l' [ ] = rev l'
  ============================
  rev_append l' [x] = rev_append l' [ ] ++ [x]
```

Now, `[] ++ [x]` is obviously the same as `[x]` but `simpl` can't simplify it and I couldn't come up with a `Lemma` that would help me here. I *did* prove `app_nil_l` (i.e. `forall (X : Type) (x : X) (l : list X), [] ++ [x] = [x].`) but when I try to rewrite with `app_nil_l` it'll rewrite both sides of the equation.

I could just define that to be an axiom, but I feel like that's cheating :-p

Thanks

Comment: `app_nil_l` will be useless here, since what you have is  `(rev_append l' [ ]) ++ [x]`, not `rev_append l' ([ ] ++ [x])`. You can confirm this with `Set Printing Parentheses.`

Comment: Thanks @ana-borges. That explains why it wasn't working. I found this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991920/logic-auxilliry-lemma-for-tr-rev-correct) and it helped me understand how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving things about definitions with accumulators has a specific trick to it. The thing is, facts about `tr_rev` must necessarily be facts about `rev_append`, but `rev_append` is defined on two lists, while `tr_rev` is defined on only one. The computation of `rev_append` depends on these two lists, and thus the induction hypothesis needs to be general enough to include both of these lists. However, if you fix the second input of `rev_append` to always be the empty list (which you implicitly do by stating your result only for `tr_rev`), then the induction hypothesis will always be too weak.

The way around this is to first prove a general result for `rev_append` by induction on `l1` (and generalizing on `l2`), and then specializing this result for the case of `tr_rev`.